# Getting high variance for blur images using opencv laplacian?

Tags: python, opencv

Code-
Have resized all my inputs images still getting high variance for some blurry images??
how do i achieve good accuracy using laplacian opencv operator

```
def variance_of_laplacian(image):
    # compute the Laplacian of the image and then return the focus
    # measure, which is simply the variance of the Laplacian
    return cv2.Laplacian(image, cv2.CV_64F).var()


# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", required=True,
    help="path to input directory of images")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type=float, default=700.0,
    help="focus measures that fall below this value will be considered 'blurry'")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


# loop over the input images
for imagePath in paths.list_images(args["images"]):
    # load the image, convert it to grayscale, and compute the
    # focus measure of the image using the Variance of Laplacian
    # method
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (500,300))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    fm = variance_of_laplacian(gray)
    text = "Not Blurry"
    # if the focus measure is less than the supplied threshold,
    # then the image should be considered "blurry"
    if fm < args["threshold"]:
        text = "Blurry"
    # show the image
    cv2.putText(image, "{}: {:.2f}".format(text, fm), (10, 30),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: The math is correct. Are you looking for advice? We can't see your images, so we can't tell the reason why few blurry images get high variance, and tell if there is a simple fix.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNWzf.png
for this type of image iam getting the high variance

Comment: Sure you are... There are no magics - you can't expect a simple statistical measurement to tell you if any image in the world is "blurred" or not.